Unit of work with DBContextFactory vs DBContext
I want to implement the Unit of Work pattern in ASP.NET Core & EF Core.
My question is whether to use the DbContextFactory or DbContext instance in the unit of work constructor. Which approach is better and why?
Code sample - using DbContextFactory:
public sealed class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private AppDbContext _dbContext;
    
    public UnitOfWork(IContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        _dbContext = contextFactory.DbContext;
    }
}

Using DbContext:
public sealed class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private AppDbContext _dbContext;
    
    public UnitOfWork(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}

While Entity Framework Core's DbContext can be considered a unit of work in the context of managing database operations, I want to implement my own unit of work pattern for managing feature plans.

If you don't plan on using pooled DbContext factory (serices.AddPooledDbContextFactory(options => ...), you should just inject DbContext (or better your actual class deriving from it) into your services.
This is easier as the dependency injection will will do all the instantiation and disposing at the end of the scope (by default end of the request).
If you intend or plan to use AddPooledDbContextFactory in future, you should use the factory. But be aware, that then it's also your task to dispose it. For that your IUnitOfWork would have to implement IDisposable too
public sealed class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private AppDbContext _dbContext;
    private bool disposing;
    
    public UnitOfWork(IContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        _dbContext = contextFactory.DbContext;
    }

    public virtual Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _dbContext?.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public sealed void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SupressFinalizer(this);
        Dispose(true);
    }
}

To ensure that memory is released as soon as possible. When using DbContext directly outside of a repository, you should releasing it as soon as you are finished dealing with it, rather than at the end of the request
using(DbContext dbContext = contextFactory.CreateContext())
{
    // Do your DbContext operations here
}
// dbContext is disposed and memory released
...
// Do other work here


what about using multiple dbcontexts with single unit of work?

You can do that too, just inject multiple different types of DbContext inside it and dispose it at the end. But may turn in a bit more complicated if you want to use transactions (and especially: distrubted transactions) as there are some limitationsa nd implications. See EF Core Transactions.
In general, distributed transactions only supported on Windows and from .NET 7+, if you want transaction between to relation dbs using DbContest you need to share the same connect etc.

So generally speaking, if you have more than one DbContext inside a Unit of Work you really really should add a form of transaction handling, because then its non-obvious (for user of the UoW) which methods change stuff in which context/data source and if you change in both, one could succeed while the other fail and you end up in inconsistent state. You also have to do that when they are separate, but for a caller its more obvious as you have to call savechanges on two different UoW instances and then think of adding the code.

On a single unit of work you would only have a single SaveChanges method so callers would expect it to handle transactions accordingly or assume its a single implementation. After all, its an implementation detail
